# How do I loop until a file with specific data inside is found in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning a lot about Node.js by rewriting some utility tools I had in C# for the fun of it. I have either found something that is not a good idea to write in Node.js or I'm completely missing a concept that will make it work.

The goal of the program: Search a directory of files for a file with data that matches some criteria. The files are gzipped XML, and for the time being I'm just looking for one tag. Here's what I tried (`files` is an array of file names):

```
while (files.length > 0) {
    var currentPath = rootDir + "\\" + files.pop();
    var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(currentPath);
    zlib.gunzip(fileContents, function(err, buff) {
        if (buff.toString().indexOf("position") !== -1) {
            console.log("The file '%s' has an odometer reading.", currentPath);
            return;
        }
    });     

    if (files.length % 1000 === 0) {
        console.log("%d files remain...", files.length);
    }
}
```

I was nervous about this when I wrote it. It's clear from the console output all of the gunzip operations are asynchronous and decide to wait until the while loop is complete. That means when I finally do get some output, `currentPath` doesn't have the value it had when the file was read, so the program is useless. I don't see a synchronous way to decompress the data with the zlip module. I don't see a way to store the context (`currentPath` would do) so the callback has the right value. I originally tried streams, piping a file stream to a gunzip stream, but I had a similar problem in that all of my callbacks happened after the loop had completed and I'd lost useful context.

It's been a long day and I'm out of ideas for how to structure this. The loop is a synchronous thing, and my asynchronous stuff depends on its state. That is bad. What am I missing? If the files weren't gzipped, this would be easy because of readFileSync().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I didn't really expect no answers at all. I got in a time crunch but I spent the last couple of days looking over Node.js, hypothesizing why certain things were working like they did, and learning about control flow.

So the code as-is doesn't work because I need a closure to capture the value of `currentPath`. Boy does Node.js like closures and callbacks. So a better structure for the application would look like this:

```
function checkFile(currentPath, fileContents) {
    var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(currentPath);
    zlib.gunzip(fileContents, function(err, buff) {
        if (buff.toString().indexOf("position") !== -1) {
            console.log("The file '%s' has an odometer reading.", currentPath);
            return;
        }
    });
}

while (files.length > 0) {
    var currentPath = rootDir + "\\" + files.shift();
    checkFile(currentPath);

}
```

But it turns out that's not very Node, since there's so much synchronous code. To do it asynchronously, I need to lean on more callbacks. The program turned out longer than I expected so I'll only post part of it for brevity, but the first bits of it look like this:

```
function checkForOdometer(currentPath, callback) {
    fs.readFile(currentPath, function(err, data) {
        unzipFile(data, function(hasReading) {
            callback(currentPath, hasReading);
        });
    });
}

function scheduleCheck(filePath, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        checkForOdometer(filePath, callback);
    });
}

var withReading = 0;
var totalFiles = 0;
function series(nextPath) {
    if (nextPath) {
        var fullPath = rootDir + nextPath;
        totalFiles++;
        scheduleCheck(fullPath, function(currentPath, hasReading) {
            if (hasReading) {
                withReading++;
                console.log("%s has a reading.", currentPath);
            }

            series(files.shift());
        });
    } else {
        console.log("%d files searched.", totalFiles);
        console.log("%d had a reading.", withReading);
    }
}

series(files.shift());
```

The reason for the series control flow is it seems if I set up the obvious parallel search I end running out of process memory, probably from having 60,000+ buffers worth of data sitting on the stack:

```
while (files.length > 0) {
    var currentPath = rootDir + files.shift();
    checkForOdometer(currentPath, function(callbackPath, hasReading) {
        //...
    });
}
```

I could probably set it up to schedule batches of, say, 50 files in parallel and wait to schedule 50 more when those are done. Setting up the series control flow seemed just as easy.